# Error Message as "This stream does not support seek operations"

Tags: c#

I am try to open  from below code using webRequest in C# Code.I have tried below code,but I am getting error message **"This stream does not support seek operations"**.  Please check this below code and advise how to do this.

```
    private static void DownloadCurrent() {
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://einvoicing
        .internal.cleartax.co/v2/eInvoice/download?
        irns=11eaf48a909dda520db27ff35804d4b42df2c3b6285afee8df586cc4dbd10541");
    webRequest.Method = "GET";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    webRequest.Headers.Add("owner_id", "78c6beda-54a2-11ea-b064-0af3f8b02c24");
    webRequest.Headers.Add("gstin", "29AAFCD5862R000");
    webRequest.Timeout = 3000;
    webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(PlayResponeAsync), webRequest);
}

private static void PlayResponeAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult) {
    long total = 0;
    long received = 0;
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;

    try {
        using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = 
            (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite("[file name to write]");
            using (Stream input = webResponse.GetResponseStream()) {
                total = input.Length;

                int size = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                while (size > 0) {
                    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, size);
                    received += size;

                    size = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
            }

            fileStream.Flush();
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Comment: on which *line* are you getting this?

Comment: To get it out of the way: Would it be an option to switch to HttpClient?

Comment: can you have example code for that??

Comment: @MarcGravell It looks like the OP is reading the contents of the response from the server and writing it to a file, the request is what they are sending to the server; I'm not sure what you mean by `you normally read from a request and write to a response`, if you read the request wouldn't you just be reading your own inputs back that you sent to the server? Admittedly I have not used `HttpWebRequest` but when I used `FtpWebRequest` I read from the response to get the results from the server.

Comment: Uh, yes. I read this as "download file, save it to disk".

Comment: @jrh fair enough; my brain stalled for a moment; I was thinking of *serving* the PDF

Comment: It seems most likely OP's exception is on the `total = input.Length` line. That certainly _can_ throw such an exception and it seems like it probably _should_ in this situation, since unless there's no way to know the length for sure until it's been fully read, which kind of would defeat the point of it being a stream. (There _might_ be a Content-Length header but there doesn't need to be.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To suggest a switch to HttpClient **if possible**:

*I left out the header-configs for brevity, but it's definitely possible to do.*

```
static string url = "https://einvoicing.internal.cleartax.co/v2/eInvoice/download?irns=11eaf48a909dda520db27ff35804d4b42df2c3b6285afee8df586cc4dbd10541";

static HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); // Use same instance over app lifetime!

static async Task DownloadCurrentAsync()
{
     // config headers here or during instance creation
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
     response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // <= Will throw if unsuccessful
     using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("[file name to write]", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
     {
         //copy the content from response to filestream
         await response.Content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
     }
}
```

Note that this is now TAP, not the legacy Async pattern (APM).

Some additional considerations:

- For resilience, I'd have a look into using "Polly" here. (I am **not** affiliated)
- The client instance should probably be injected through IHttpClientFactory.

Addendum:

If the rest of your app is using exclusively APM, then you could have a look into [Interop with Other Asynchronous Patterns and Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types)

Comment: "For resilience" -- Yes, unfortunately the Microsoft `HttpClient`, `FtpWebRequest`, and other classes like this have some [serious](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/139474/ftp-file-upload-queue) [problems](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/conversation/ftpwebrequest-discussion). I usually don't like third party libraries, but this is one case where I think you have very little to lose by looking at other options, I'm pretty sure these bugs never got fixed.

Comment: Thanks for reply... but I can not find the content in pdf file.please check my updated code.

Comment: I saw the proposed edits. Problem was: you need to set headers before the call to `GetAsync`.

Comment: @jrh Polly gives you "policies" where you can very comfortably configure "retry" or "timeout" , "fallback" and the like. It integrates nicely with DI and IHttpFactory and is - despite being 3rd party - widely used. So that's what "resilience" means here.

Comment: Why the above code not working in visual studio 2010??

Comment: With VS 2010 you probably cannot target a Framework Version that has HttpClient? That's really more than vintage.

Comment: @Materials it looks like `HttpClient` got added in .NET 4.5, VS2010 is .NET 4.0. These days you should probably apply the appropriate tag if you're targeting older versions of VS. Quite a lot still works on 2010 but not everything. FWIW "vintage" is a bit exaggerated, though, IMO. Certain industries won't get any real disruption from using .NET 4.0. Something like .NET 1.1, on the other hand.... not so much.

Comment: @jrh a little tongue in cheek it was indeed